# Toolbar menu icon not display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, menuitem

I know may be duplicate but i am not finding any solution for that.
Actually, i want to show menu with text and icon inside **fragment** which having a toolbar, i have just add one line in **fragment** to show menu is

```
    class JustTry : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_try, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var mToolbar = view!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.dashboard_menu)
    }

}
```

[image]

I got this output from this code.

here is my menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Messages" />

</menu>
```

My question is why i am not getting **Icon in Message and Home** items even i am adding **android:icon** tag.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:balloonberry="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
     android:id="@+id/menu_item"
     android:icon="@drawable/img_menu"
     balloonberry:showAsAction="always">
     <menu>
         <item
             android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
             android:title="delete"
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>
         <item
             android:id="@+id/btn_message"
             android:title="Message"
             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"/>


          </menu>
      </item>


 </menu>
```

Comment: No, this is not i am asking, i want to show icon inside menu overflow icon